# Laravel 5 middleware error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, middleware

I keep getting an error every time I use myroute middleware. Below is the middleware class. its currently empty.

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class EnforceHttps
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

When I attach it to my route like so it gives me an error.

```
Route::get('/', ['middleware' =>'https',function () {
//Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('launch');
}]);
```

If I uncomment the line below which does not include the middleware instead all is good. Why is this?

Comment: NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161

Comment: May I add that my error does not exist when I access the website through 'https' before the URL on my local wamp server but I receive this error with 'http'. Whats up?

Comment: Show how you have included this middleware

Comment: Did you add it to `app\Http\Kernel.php` ?

Comment: Post your kernel.php.

Comment: Also, route cache once.

Comment: `['middleware' =>'https', 'use' => function () {`